# Using Redis to store results from a query from neo4j

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j, redis

I have a query in neo4j with some aggregation functions, which takes around 10 seconds to retrieve the information. What I would like to do is store the query results into redis and from time to time the redis database would update the results from neo4j.

One record will be like:

```
{ entry: "123", model: "abc", reactants: [{specie: "abc@12", color: "black"}], .... }
```

I'm using node.js with express, thank you in advance for your attention

UPDATE: my query is quite extensive, I had to do that 'UNWIND' part to be able to search by the reactants (I wanted the products too but I didn't know how to do it). I don't know if it's possible to be optimized to at least 2 seconds but here it goes:

```
MATCH (rx:ModelReaction),
      (rx)-[l:left_component]->(lc:MetaboliteSpecie), 
      (rx)-[r:right_component]->(rc:MetaboliteSpecie) 
      OPTIONAL MATCH (rx)-[:has_gpr]-(gpr:Root) 
      OPTIONAL MATCH (rx)-[:has_crossreference_to]-(cr)-[:has_ec_number]-(ec)
WITH rx,r,cr,ec,gpr, 
     COLLECT(DISTINCT {specie: l.cpdEntry, stoichiometry: l.stoichiometry}) as reacts 
UNWIND reacts as rcts 
WITH rx,r,cr,ec,gpr, rcts, reacts 
WHERE rcts.specie =~ {searchText} OR rx.entry =~ {searchText} OR 
      rx.name =~ {searchText} OR (ec.entry IS NOT NULL AND 
      ec.entry =~ {searchText}) OR rx.geneRule =~ {searchText} 
RETURN {entry: rx.entry, 
    reactants: reacts, 
    products:COLLECT(DISTINCT {specie: r.cpdEntry, 
                               stoichiometry: r.stoichiometry}), 
    orientation: rx.orientation, name: rx.name, ecnumber: ec.entry, 
    gpr_rule: rx.geneRule, gpr_normalized: gpr.normalized_rule}
    ORDER BY ' + reactionsTableMap[sortCol] + ' ' + order + ' SKIP {offset} LIMIT {number}'
```

Comment: Perhaps we can also have a look at your Neo4j query to see if it can be optimized?

Comment: I updated my question with the query, thanks for replying

Comment: @chris (if it's still relevant) you might want to consider using RedisGraph. It can provides you Graph DB capability with Redis performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest is to store the result from Neo4j as a JSON string in redis, and set an expiry time on that key. Now when you need to retrieve the data, you check if the key is there, then redis serves as a cache, and if the key is not there, you ask Neo4j, store the result in redis and returns that to your Node.js program.

Pseudo code since I don't know Node.js specifics regarding Neo4J and Redis:

```
var result = redis.get("Record:123")
if (result == null) {
    result = neo4j.query("...");
    redis.setex("Record:123", toJson(result), 10); // set with expiry time
}
return result;
```

Redis will handle the expiry so you don't have to.

If you want to store them all, you can store them in a LIST or a ZSET (sorted set by record Id for example) and just call redis `LRANGE`/`ZRANGE` to retrieve a part of that list/set

Example with list:

```
var exist = redis.exist("Records"); // check if something stored in redis
if (!exist) {
    var queryResult = neo4j.query("...); // get a list of results from neo4j
    queryResult.foreach(result => redis.lpush("Records", toJson(result))); // add the results in the redis list
}
return redis.lrange("Records", 0, 50); // get the 50 first items
```

Now just iterate on that using the two parameters of `redis.lrange` by getting the ten items then the next ten.

You can also call redis `EXPIRE` to set an expiry time on the redis list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I just want to store all the records (around 100 000) and retrieve 10 at a time, and with some filtering with the search. From what I understand from your answer then, with something like (1, "{entry:.....}"), I would store all that in redis, and redirect the GET request to redis to retrieve the data. If you could answer me now the search part, how can I search in redis by the JSON fields? Thank you again for your answer

Comment: When to time expires the Records on redis will be deleted and then the 'if' statement (if (!exist)) fails and updates redis right? Also I want to be able to search by some parameters if possible and order the records by some parameter too, like the neo4j query that I put in my main question

Comment: the redis `EXPIRE` command set an expiry time on any key, after which the key is simply deleted by redis therefore the `EXIST` commands returns `false`. If you want to order the results with some parameters just do that using Neo4J, only use redis as a cache for the request it will be easier.